# ng-view div is rendered twice when $interval calls service that does a $route.reload

Tags: angularjs, routes, setinterval, reload, ng-view

Pretend my app is a news reader.  It refreshes to fetch incoming news every X seconds.

You've scrolled halfway down the page.  Then, the ng-view auto refreshes.

If I did nothing, you would lose your place as the scroll is kicked back up to the top of the page.

So, just before the refresh I use a service to record the numerical location of the scroll.  I refresh.  I reset the scroll to the old value.  You should be at your old scroll location.  Doesn't work.

What actually happens is, as I step through the code, during the reload the ng-div is rendered twice.

On the screen and in the DOM I can see the "old" ng-view full of content.

I can also see, at the same time, a "new" ng-view, same name, same everything, living in the dom as a sibling of the "old" ng-view.

I am stunned as I did not expect this at any time in the cycle.

The new ng-view is completely devoid of content.

I successfully extract the scroll location.  I attempt to set the scroll location on the new div, but when angular does its thing beyond my control, the new div is rendered and filled with content - and the scroll is set to the top. My old setting is ignored / destroyed.

I have tried for an embarrassing amount of time to find a way to address the scroll location of the "new" ng-view only, after all the dust has settled, every time after each refresh, but ...

Any hints, tips, tricks, rumors, greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here are the relevant snippets of the code:

THE VIEW : (ng-view is class 'hog')

```
    <!--        HEADER      -->
    <img  ng-id='colonade' ng-show="showPageHero"  class='header jumbo' src="components/jumbotron/x.png" />

    <header ng-include="'components/header/header.html'">
    </header>


    <!--        VIEWPORT    - GETS RENDERED TWICE AT ONE POINT  -->
    <div ng-view class="column col-md-11 center-block hog" id="viewport" >
    </div>

    <div class="ng-enter" ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'">
    </div>
```

THE CONTROLLER :

```
app.controller(
    'Controller'    , 
    function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $interval, $route, pane)
    {
        console.log("at Controller");
        var curscroll;

        $rootScope.$on(
            "$locationChangeStart"   , 
            function(event, next, current) 
            {
                console.log("at $locationChangeStart - only the first time");
                //***  Take note when the URL changes.
                $scope.showPageHero = $location.path() === '/'; 

                console.log("at $locationChangeStart - setting interval");

                // Have tried different values for X, from 3,000 to 60,000
                $interval(pane.refreshReroll, X);
            }
        );

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        console.log('beforeunload');
    });                


    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
        curscroll = pane.scrollLocationGet();
        console.log("at $routeChangeStart, curscroll=" +curscroll);
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
        console.log("at $routeChangeSuccess, about to set scroll to " +curscroll); 
        pane.scrollLocationSet(curscroll);
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
          console.log("at $viewContentLoaded, about to set scroll to " +curscroll); 
          pane.scrollLocationSet(curscroll);
    });

    $scope.repeat = pane.scrollLocationGet();

    }
);
```

THE SERVICE:

```
app.service('pane', function($route, $window) {

    // comes here once at start
    console.log('in service pane');
    var _scrollLocation;

    return {
                scrollLocationGet: scrollLocationGet,
                scrollLocationSet: scrollLocationSet,
                refreshReroll: refreshReroll
    };

    function scrollLocationGet(){     
        return angular.element(document.getElementById('viewport')).scrollTop(); 
    }

    function scrollLocationSet(val){
        var hogs=angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('hog'));
        if (hogs.length > 1){
            // At this point I have TWO ng-views in the DOM
            angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('hog'))[0].scrollTop = 124;            
            angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('hog'))[1].scrollTop = 124;
        }


    }

    function refreshReroll() {
        console.log('at refreshReroll - about to reload');
        $route.reload();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cancel the $interval on route-change

```
      $scope.stopTime = $interval(updateTime, 1000);

      $scope.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel($scope.stopTime);
      });
```

RTFD [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and [more](http://informationideas.com/news/2015/01/15/angularjs-interval-example/)